# How Can I Update the property of an object based on another one updated at the same time - zustand?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, zustand

I have a product and i want to get the total price of this product based on quantity, I'm using zustand for state management.

here's a function I used to update the state.

```
export const useCartProduct = create<CartProductsProp>(
  devtools(
    persist(
       (set) => ({
         incrementProductQuantity: (product: ProductProps) => {
          set((prev) => {
            console.log('@userQuantity-product', product.userQuantity);
            let currentCart = prev.cartProducts.map((cartProduct) =>
              cartProduct.id === product.id
                ? {
                    ...cartProduct,
                    userQuantity: cartProduct.userQuantity + 1,
                    productTotalPrice: cartProduct.userQuantity * cartProduct.price, // here's the issue "the userQuantity not updated and return the prev value".
                  }
                : cartProduct,
            );
            return {
              cartProducts: currentCart,
            };
          });
        },
      }),
    ),
  ),
);
```

the issue here

```
  productTotalPrice: cartProduct.userQuantity * cartProduct.price
```

*"the `userQuantity` not updated and return the prev value".*

So what I tried is like this

```
  productTotalPrice: (cartProduct.userQuantity + 1) * cartProduct.price,
```

that's return the correct quantity 'updated one', So is others way to fix it?

Comment: Try to read about React Hooks. To be specific, `useState` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
Then, combine it with `useEffect` Hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: @JerryBen But it's not related specifically to my issue (with zustand)